# Laravel Request Validation Custom Function with multiple attributes

Tags: laravel, validation, request

I'm currently working on a project where tenders need to fill in API credentials. I want to make sure the credentials are fine before saving.

I want to make a custom validation rule where I use the username and password to make a call to the API, to check if the credentials are oke. I can add the validation rule to api_username, but because of the protected $validator->data attribute, I can't get the password.

Can anybody help me with this?

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|string',
        'api_username' => 'required|string|min:32|max:32|api_cred_check',
        'api_password' => 'required|string|min:32|max:32',
    ];
}

public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->addExtension('api_cred_check', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        //Use credentials to make call to API.
    });

    $validator->addReplacer('api_cred_check', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters, $validator) {
        //Message if Username and Password won't match.
    });
}
```

Comment: In validator, you must validate fields, not check creditinals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can also use clouser as custom validation like this**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|string',
        'api_username' => ['required', 'string', 'min:32', 'max:32', function ($attr, $value, $fail) {
            // You can use guzzle Http here to make an API call 
        }],
        'api_password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:32', 'max:32', function ($attr, $value, $fail) {
            // You can check if Username and Password is wrong.
        }],
    ];
}
```

**Use the last param $fail as a function $fail('With your desired message if validation fails.');**